# Get System Profiler Information from Time Machine Backup

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to get my system profiler .spx file from a Time Machine backup. Specifically, I wish to know the serial number of the hard drive in my Mac. The first place I looked was `/private/var/tmp/sysdiagnose_date/system_profiler.spx`, but it appears that Time Machine doesn't back up the tmp folder. I'm running OS X 10.8.2.

Any help would be much appreciated!